# Selecting Row After Render/Table Load

Tags: tabulator

I'm attempting to select a row within a Tabulator table once the data or table has been rendered/loaded. I'm not particularly fussed which callback is used, but when a user navigates to this page the table should load a predetermined record (which I will parse as a parameter).

The callback itself works well, as I can display a JS alert, however I'm still unable to select a line within Tabulator.

```
//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator(
    "#example-table", {
        height: (window.innerHeight), // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically
        headerFilterPlaceholder: '', //default place holder text for filters
        selectable: 1, //allows row within table to be selected and have selected state (not to be confused with row click function), can be set to have multiple selected (integer), true or false
        data: [ **DATA1** ], //assign data to table
        dataTree: true,
        dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
        dataTreeBranchElement: false, //adds or removes right angle leading from parent to child
        dataTreeChildIndent: 25, //changes the indent padding
        dataTreeCollapseElement: !1,
        dataTreeStartExpanded: !0, //changes whether or not the entire table begins expanded
        dataTreeCollapseElement: "<span>▼ </span>",
        dataTreeExpandElement: "<span>► </span>",
        layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns: [ **COLUMN1** ],
        rowClick:function(e, row) //triggered when the row is clicked
        {
            var scriptParam = **SCRIPTPARAM1**;
            var rowId = row.getData().id;
            var fieldName = **FIELDNAME1**;
            var theList = [scriptParam, rowId, fieldName];
            var doThis = "fmp://$/**FILE**?script=**SCRIPT1**&param=" + theList;
            window.location.href = doThis;
        },
        rowDblClick:function(e, row) //triggered when the row is double clicked
        {
            table.selectRow(**ROWID**);
        },
        rowContext:function(e, row) //triggered when the row is right clicked
        {
            alert('right click');
            e.preventDefault(); //overrides the browsers native right click function
        },
        cellEdited: function(cell)
        {
            var parameter = 1.1;
            var distribute = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().distribute;
            var id = cell.getData().id;
            var table = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().fmTable;
            var field = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().fmTable + "::" + cell.getColumn().getDefinition().fmField;
            var table = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().fmTable;
            var scriptBefore = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().script_before;
            var scriptAfter = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().script_after;
            var value = cell.getValue();
            var theList = [parameter, distribute, id, table, field, value];
            var doThis = "fmp://$/**FileName**?script=**ScriptName**&param=" + theList;
            window.location.href = doThis;
        },
        rowFormatter: function(row) {
            var rowColor = row.getData().color
            row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = rowColor;
        },
        renderComplete:function()
        {
            table.selectRow(**ROWID**);
        }
    }
);
```

I'm expecting that once the page is loaded, the row I defined as `**ROWID**` (which for my testing is ID 1) is selected. FYI, the double click function (regardless of which row is clicked) performs as expected, selecting the correct row.

To further this, I'm looking to (at times) select a child row of the data tree, for example:

```
const tabledata1 = [{
        id: "1",
        name: "Oli Bob",
        location: "United Kingdom",
        gender: "male",
        col: "red",
        dob: "14/04/1984",
        _children: [{
                id: "2",
                name: "Mary May",
                location: "Germany",
                gender: "female",
                col: "blue",
                dob: "14/05/1982"
            },
            {
                name: "Christine Lobowski",
                location: "France",
                gender: "female",
                col: "green",
                dob: "22/05/1982"
            },
            {
                name: "Brendon Philips",
                location: "USA",
                gender: "male",
                col: "orange",
                dob: "01/08/1980",
                _children: [{
                        name: "Margret Marmajuke",
                        location: "Canada",
                        gender: "female",
                        col: "yellow",
                        dob: "31/01/1999"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Frank Harbours",
                        location: "Russia",
                        gender: "male",
                        col: "red",
                        dob: "12/05/1966"
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Jamie Newhart",
        location: "India",
        gender: "male",
        col: "green",
        dob: "14/05/1985"
    },
    {
        name: "Gemma Jane",
        location: "China",
        gender: "female",
        col: "red",
        dob: "22/05/1982",
        _children: [{
            name: "Emily Sykes",
            location: "South Korea",
            gender: "female",
            col: "maroon",
            dob: "11/11/1970"
        }, ]
    },
    {
        name: "James Newman",
        location: "Japan",
        gender: "male",
        col: "red",
        dob: "22/03/1998"
    },
];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
    selectable: true, //make rows selectable
    layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    autoColumns: true,
    dataTree: true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
    renderComplete: function() {
        console.log('done');
        this.selectRow(2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> table.selectRow(**ROWID**); wont work until table is initialized you
>   have to do this.selectRow

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/0gLb1v2x/80/)

```
  renderComplete: function() {
    const rows = this.getRows();
    console.log('rows', rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      const childRows = rows[i].getTreeChildren();
      if (childRows.length > 0) {
        // console.log('childRows', childRows);

        // this.selectRow(childRows);
        for (let j = 0; j < childRows.length; j++) {
          const gender = childRows[j].getData().gender;
          console.log('gender', gender);
          if (gender === 'male') {
            this.selectRow(childRows[j]);
            const childRows2 = childRows[j].getTreeChildren();

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, and yes that works well. However, I'm looking to select a child row within a data tree. I've modified your code (amended to the above post) to demonstrate

Comment: *"selectable is boolean you have assigned a number to it"*

From my understanding this can be true, false or an integer. An integer dictates how many rows can be selected at once (hence the 1).

Comment: Again, thank you so much, I really am extremely grateful! But (apologies), I am hoping that I can select a row (child or parent) on render by parsing the ID. I will look at what you have provided me, but any thoughts and experience you could share would be amazing!

Comment: Interesting thought. I am creating the ID's manually and parsing them, so I guess my question would be, can I select a child row with a field that I have parsed (such as name, ID, etc.). Any suggestions?

You've been fantastic, and I really do appreciate it. We've gotten a long way so far, now all we need to do is select individual lines rather than all (conditionally).

Comment: you can play with data i edited my fiddle to select rows where its only gender is male